# I am getting an empty dictionary from my discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

I have this code for discord bot:

```
`from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)


async def process_message(message):
    user_data = {'username': '', 'link': '', 'command': ''}

    if message.content.startswith('/click'):
        parts = message.content.split(' ')
        user_data['username'] = parts[1]
        user_data['link'] = parts[2]
        user_data['command'] = parts[3]
    return user_data


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    user_data = await process_message(message)
    print(user_data)

    await bot.process_commands(message)`
```

In discord I am sending this command **/click Ms.Azazel #/battle=2aaaaabaf64e2379 A**
And the bot gives me empty dictionary like this: ***{'username': '', 'link': '', 'command': ''}***
I need this ***{'username': 'Ms.Azazel', 'link': '#/battle=2aaaaabaf64e2379', 'command': 'A'}***

I tryied to modify all code but cant do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't enable the `message_content` intent, so you can't read messages. Hence, `message.content.startswith(...)` is always `False`.

Docs for [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20content#discord.Message.content):

> The actual contents of the message. **If Intents.message_content is not enabled this will always be an empty string unless the bot is mentioned or the message is a direct message.**

You already managed to enable the `members` intent, so I hope enabling `message_content` should be trivial.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

PS consider not using `/` as a prefix, it's annoying for users because of slash commands that open up a menu in the GUI. You can always create an actual slash command instead of a message command if you really want to use it.

Comment: I guess i enabled correctly message_contet, but it still gives me empty dictionary

Comment: @Александрxs, if you've enabled all your intents correctly on your Discord Developer Portal, using `intents = discord.Intents.all()` is easier. All other methods are prone to problems, as Discord and discord.py updates are very problematic. See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html#presence-intent

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder you shouldn't enable intents that you don't need. If you don't need _all_ intents, don't use it. `presences` is especially problematic, so enabling it (through `all()`) when you don't need it is a bad idea

Comment: @Александрxs what does your code look like now? Did you enable it on your portal as well? Can you print the content of the message & see what comes out?

Comment: yea, thank you both very much, now its working as i wanted <3